# how to make list of history tests?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want make app with math questions and after the test the result saved in Shared preference and will be Activity with the last ten tests.
i know how to make the question and i know how to intent to the activitys and i know how to save data in shared preference and how to take data from shared preference, but i dont know how i make the list of last ten tests, i try to do list of 4 test, i do it like this:

first after the test i save the result like this:

```
                sharedL1 = getSharedPreferences("List", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                edit = sharedL1.edit();
                edit.putString("List","Easy Game");
                edit.apply();
```

in the test activity before i put the saved data i take the data from the other test like this:

```
  sharedL1 = getSharedPreferences("List2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        edit = sharedL1.edit();
        edit.putString("List2",L1T.getText().toString());
        edit.apply();

        sharedL1 = getSharedPreferences("List3", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        edit = sharedL1.edit();
        edit.putString("List3",L2T.getText().toString());
        edit.apply();

        sharedL1 = getSharedPreferences("List4", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        edit = sharedL1.edit();
        edit.putString("List4",L3T.getText().toString());
        edit.apply();
```

and put the data like this:

```
            sharedL1 = getSharedPreferences("List", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        L1T.setText(sharedL1.getString("List",""));

        sharedL1 = getSharedPreferences("List2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        L2T.setText(sharedL1.getString("List2",""));

        sharedL1 = getSharedPreferences("List3", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        L3T.setText(sharedL1.getString("List3",""));

        sharedL1 = getSharedPreferences("List4", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        L4T.setText(sharedL1.getString("List4",""));
```

please help me to make this work:)

Thanks in advance!